# Developing Data and User Models :: Tools / Best Practices / Approaches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, database-design, model

I'm finding that it's difficult to clearly articulate the specific models I want to create at times - especially as projects get bigger and I have to wrap my head around the relationships between everything.

How do you organize your data and user models?  Do you sketch them out on paper?  Maybe there's a neat tool online?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I believe good old pencil and paper are the tools to use for that. Keeping in mind that eventually your models will access the database through an object *relational* mapper, you should think in relations.

Mostly, it is worthwhile to think in relations first and then figure out names for your models. Consider the following case where you need something that stores the following:

- posts need to be stored
- comments need to be stored
- users have to be stored

Now, before you think about how you name each of these, rather think about how they are related. I find that mostly by doing that, you will choose the right names intuitively:

A post belongs to a user, a user has many posts, a comment belongs to a post, a post has many comments, a user has many comments, a comment belongs to a user.

In this last rather intuitive sentence, you have everything you need: names and relations. Rails supports this intuition because it is so idiomatic.

This is as far as planning databases and models goes - if you have an existing application and need to figure out the models' relations, I recommend using a UML ([unified modelling language](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)) gem called [railroady](https://github.com/preston/railroady), which will automatically create a nice graphical overview of your application's data.

Answer (score 0):

I find visualisation to be a huge help in establishing a data model and working on data flow diagrams etc.. Pencil and paper has never worked for me because I get all neatness obsessed and hate making changes and redoing things, and I also don't want to get distracted by moving little boxes around on a screen to make them look nice as it breaks the "creative flow".

I've used GraphViz http://www.graphviz.org/ for this in the past for a number of reasons.

First, I've worked for a lot of companies too cheap to spend money on any software that might accidentally help software development.

Secondly, the text input is distraction free -- it lets you concentrate on content without the distractions. The text input can also be generated by code, so it's been great for (semi)automatic code and schema visualisation.

Third, the input text can be added to the source code repository and commented and change-tracked.

I recently discovered http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/ which has made it even easier -- don't forget to click on them ad links.